# press to zoom/pan image in flutter

Tags: flutter, image, user-interface, zooming

I want to zoom an image ( which is already loaded to an ImageProvider ) to 2x when I press my finger on the image. It should also move the zoomed part of the image when I pan my finger over it.

I'm already working on a class right now but I'm stumped on several topics.

Assuming the image is 1920x1080 and container is 640x360:

- I think to properly do this we need a 640x360 rendered image which works when you put the image directly in container with fit: BoxFit.contain or BoxFit.fill ( container aspect ratio will be same as the image ) and also a 1280x720 rendered image which will be used when I press my finger.
- There are some zoom widgets but most of them works by doubling the pixel density in an area. If an image is rendered in 640x360 and zoomed in by these widgets, image is still 640x360 but doubled in pixels in width and height. **This is not real zoom.**
- When user presses finger on the center of the image, it should crop [ 320,180-959,539 ] coordinates of 1280x720 image and replace it with the 640x360 image.
- Again when you move your finger it should update cropped part of the image to keep zoom.

I already prepared a foundation for this. Though I lack some information:

- I'm using cached network image to cache the image to local repository and access the ImageProvider object. So, the 1920x1080 image is already in memory ( in ImageProvider ).
- I need to scale and crop this imageProvider for my needs. I'm not sure how to keep this scaled/cropped part of the image though. There is no container with 1280x720 resolution to put an Image into it. So this should be in memory and accessible.
- I need to access the cropped part of the image instantaneously and replace it.

Here is the code I wrote. The only parts missing is already explained above.

ignore the zoomed image part for now, it doesn't work.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class ZoomImage extends StatefulWidget {
  final ImageProvider image;
  const ZoomImage(this.image, {super.key});

  @override
  State<ZoomImage> createState() => _ZoomImageState();
}

class _ZoomImageState extends State<ZoomImage> {
  bool zoomed = false;
  int imageHeight = 0;
  int imageWidth = 0;
  double cropX = 0;
  double cropY = 0;
  double cropWidth = 0;
  double cropHeight = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    widget.image
        .resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty)
        .addListener(ImageStreamListener((image, synchronousCall) {
      imageHeight = image.image.height;
      imageWidth = image.image.width;

      print('Image loaded: ${image.image.width}x${image.image.height}');
    }));

    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        cropWidth = constraints.maxWidth;
        cropHeight = imageHeight * cropWidth / imageWidth;

        widget.image.resolve(ImageConfiguration.empty);

        return GestureDetector(
          onTapDown: (details) {
            print('Tap down: ${details.localPosition}');
            print('width: $cropWidth, height: $cropHeight');

            print(
                'Image x = ${(details.localPosition.dx * imageWidth / cropWidth).round()} '
                'y = ${(details.localPosition.dy * imageHeight / cropHeight).round()}');

            if (!zoomed) {
              setState(() {
                cropX = (details.localPosition.dx * imageWidth / cropWidth);
                cropY = (details.localPosition.dy * imageHeight / cropHeight);
                zoomed = true;
              });
            }
          },
          onPanStart: (details) {
            print('Pan start: ${details.localPosition}');
            setState(() {
              cropX = (details.localPosition.dx * imageWidth / cropWidth);
              cropY = (details.localPosition.dy * imageHeight / cropHeight);
              zoomed = true;
            });
          },
          onPanUpdate: (details) {
            print(details.localPosition);
            setState(() {
              cropX = (details.localPosition.dx * imageWidth / cropWidth);
              cropY = (details.localPosition.dy * imageHeight / cropHeight);
            });
          },
          onPanEnd: (details) {
            print('Pan end');
            setState(() {
              zoomed = false;
            });
          },
          onTapUp: (details) {
            print('Tap up');
            setState(() {
              zoomed = false;
            });
          },
          child: (zoomed)
              ? Image(
                  alignment: Alignment(-cropX / cropWidth, -cropY / cropHeight),
                  width: cropWidth,
                  height: cropHeight,
                  image: widget.image,
                )
              : Image(
                  image: widget.image,
                  fit: BoxFit.contain,
                ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

How can I manage to make this work ( again without losing detail ).